# Flutter Bloc + Socket.io + Freezed implementation

Tags: flutter, socket.io, bloc, flutter-bloc, freezed

How to implement [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) to [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) with [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

socket_bloc.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';

part 'socket_bloc.freezed.dart';
part 'socket_event.dart';
part 'socket_state.dart';

class SocketBloc extends Bloc<SocketEvent, SocketState> {
  late final Socket _socket;

  SocketBloc() : super(SocketState.initial()) {
    _socket = io(
      'http://localhost:1337',
      OptionBuilder()
          .setTimeout(3000)
          .setReconnectionDelay(5000)
          .disableAutoConnect()
          .build(),
    );

    _socket.onConnecting((data) => add(_SocketConnectingEvent()));
    _socket.onConnect((_) => add(_SocketOnConnect()));
    _socket.onConnectError((data) => add(_SocketConnectErrorEvent()));
    _socket.onConnectTimeout((data) => add(_SocketConnectTimeoutEvent()));
    _socket.onDisconnect((_) => add(_SocketOnDisconnect()));
    _socket.onError((data) => add(_SocketErrorEvent()));
    _socket.on('joined', (data) => add(_SocketJoinedEvent()));

    // User events
    on<_SocketConnect>((event, emit) {
      _socket.connect();
    });

    on<_SocketDisconnect>((event, emit) {
      _socket.disconnect();
    });
    // Socket events
    on<_SocketConnectingEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketState.connected("Connecting"));
    });
    on<_SocketOnConnect>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketState.connected(_socket.id!));
    });
    on<_SocketConnectErrorEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketState.connected("Connection Error"));
    });
    on<_SocketConnectTimeoutEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketState.connected("Connection timeout"));
    });
    on<_SocketOnDisconnect>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketState.disconnected());
    });
    on<_SocketErrorEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketState.connected("ErrorEvent"));
    });
    on<_SocketJoinedEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(SocketState.connected("JoinedEvent"));
    });
  }
  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _socket.dispose();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

socket_event.dart

```
part of 'socket_bloc.dart';

@freezed
class SocketEvent with _$SocketEvent {
  const factory SocketEvent.connect() = _SocketConnect;
  const factory SocketEvent.connecting() = _SocketConnectingEvent;
  const factory SocketEvent.onConnect() = _SocketOnConnect;
  const factory SocketEvent.onConnectError() = _SocketConnectErrorEvent;
  const factory SocketEvent.onConnectTimeout() = _SocketConnectTimeoutEvent;
  const factory SocketEvent.onError() = _SocketErrorEvent;
  const factory SocketEvent.onJoined() = _SocketJoinedEvent;
  const factory SocketEvent.disconnect() = _SocketDisconnect;
  const factory SocketEvent.onDisconnect() = _SocketOnDisconnect;
}
```

socket_state.dart

```
part of 'socket_bloc.dart';

@freezed
class SocketState with _$SocketState {
  const factory SocketState.initial() = _SocketInitial;
  const factory SocketState.connected(String status) = _SocketConnected;
  const factory SocketState.disconnected() = _SocketDisonnected;
}
```

Also dont forget to run `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`